# MouseUp and MouseDown always have the same object sender

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseevent, minesweeper

I'm trying to make a minesweeper clone and i'm having trouble with the mouse events. If i press a mousebutton on a picturebox and then move the mouse to another box, the mouseup event will still have the same object sender even though it happens on another control.

I need the mousedown event so that i can see if both mouse buttons have been pressed, unfortunately the mouseup event doesn't seem to care where the cursor is when i release the button.

If i'm not expressing myself clearly, think minesweeper. I want to be able to leftclick, rightclick, click both together and also be able to move the cursor after pressing down and open the tile where i release it.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Mouse is captured by the `Control` on which the `MouseDown` occurred.

Comment: Yeah that's the problem, there must be some way to accomplish the same mouse mechanics as in the original minesweeper though.

Comment: The original MineSweeper did not use controls for each tile.  It was just painted.

Comment: Maybe i should just check the location of the click and calculate which tile was clicked and not bother with events for specific controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure something out that will do the trick, gonna leave it here if someone else needs it in the future.

```
private void MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point ptCursor = Cursor.Position;
        ptCursor = PointToClient(ptCursor);
        PictureBox pBox = (PictureBox)GetChildAtPoint(ptCursor);
        pBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
    }
```

I set up a simple form with some pictureboxes and when the mouseup-event happens it checks for the control under the cursors position and you can then use that for your needs. The problem i was having was that the mouseup event was tied to the control where the mousedown-event happened, and thus i couldn't access the control the cursor was in when the mouseup-event happened.

I have only been programming for about 4 weeks so this solution might be very flawed so if there are any problems with it some feedback would be great.

Comment: I should add that you need a try-catch aswell since it will crash if you release the mousebutton where there is no picturebox.

Comment: It might be better to explicitly check that the return of `GetChildAtPoint()` is a PictureBox like `var pBox = GetChildAtPoint(ptCursor) as PictureBox; if (pBox != null) {…}` instead of using a `try {…} catch {…}` block.

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this:

1. Create subclassed buttons to contain game assets as theire picture.
2. Create a custom control and add as many as buttons necessary
3. On mouse click I would check agains `Contains` method of the `Bounds` to see if the click occured on that specific button, or another way handle the button click inside the custom controll

It would help more if we see some of your code and propably a screenshot.

Update:

This is an example of how to handle clicks, using delegates.

```
public partial class MineSweeper : UserControl
{
    public MineSweeper()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MineSweeper_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.BackColor = Color.Red;
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            var button = new Button();
            button.Name = "Button" + i;
            button.Size = new Size(50, 50);
            button.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;

            button.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            button.Click += delegate
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You have clicked me! I am " + button.Name);
            };
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(button);
            flowLayoutPanel1.Invalidate();
        }

        this.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Just add a new UserControl from the designer, add a flowLayoutPanel to it and set its dock property to full.

Comment: Well the code is very spread out into pieces but what iv'e done is that i have created the grid out of pictureboxes that i store in an array. I store what's under each tile in a separate array. I tried handling the mouseclicks with the pictureboxes mousedown and mouseup events but that is causing some problems since they don't really function the way the mouseclicks did in minesweeper.                                  What i need is a click event that checks which control the cursor is on when the button is released, not where it is when first pressed.

Comment: Isn't the box.click going to work just like the other click event in winforms though? The main problem is that i need a click method that ignores where the mousedown occurred and only cares where the moseup happens.

Comment: @Lito in that case just change `Click` to `MouseUp`. I would put some time and paste some code and screenshots...I still have a hardtime figuring out what you really need.

Comment: I would think the FlowLayoutPanel would be the wrong type of container to use.  Minesweeper is a grid.  The developer needs to have simple access to the neighboring tiles in all directions.  BTW, there is no reason to call those `Invalidate()` methods if you aren't drawing anything.

Comment: @LarsTech You are perfectly right, I just used that to quickly put buttons in order.

Comment: A mouseclick starts when you press the mousebutton down, and finishes when you release it. I want to be able to press the mousebutton down in one control, release it in another and have the event tied to where i release it instead of where i initially press it down.  Unfortunately, even when using a mouseup-event, it registers the control the cursor is in when i first press it down and doesn't care that i have moved the cursor to another control.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I do this by having a form level Point variable that I update on every MouseMove event.  Then, when the other mouse events happen, they have the latest available.

Comment: That would mean i would have to calculate which control the cursor is on based on the cursors coordinates, right?

Comment: Yes.  So make them 8 by pixels or 16 by 16.  Then, for the 8 pixels, do x = e.locations.X>>3;  for 16 , e.Location.X >> 4;  It automagically gives you the index.

Answer (score 0):

[VS 2017 c#] Using `MouseEventArgs` for mouse position at mouse down/up works only when the point is captured inside left mouse button as shown below.

```
private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   //??? this changes at UP time and becomes same as MouseArgsUpPoint 
   //MouseArgsDownPoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
   //same as above, MouseArgsDownPoint = PointToClient(MousePosition);

   if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
   {
       //inside here it works fine and Up/Down points are different and correct
       MouseArgsDownPoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
   }
}


private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    MouseArgsUpPoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
}
```